# How to Use In Jw player Different Preview Images for Mobile and Desktop

Tags: javascript, wordpress, jwplayer

I'm using "jw player plugin" in wordpress and I want to use different preview images for desktop and mobile devices.

I'm trying to add it as JavaScript. But this code isn't working:

```
jwplayer.utils.isMobile()?"http://internetzengini.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/mobileimage.png":"http://internetzengini.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/desktopimage.png";
```

How can I make this work as JS?

Thanks from now for all the helps.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to do a different set up entirely for mobile vs desktop.

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) != null || navigator.userAgent.match(/android/i) != null){
//SET UP PLAYER WITH ONE PREVIEW IMAGE HERE
} else {
//SET UP PLAYER WITH A DIFFERENT PREVIEW IMAGE HERE
}
```

Comment: I'm adding the player via shortcode, and I was able to start/stop on video clicking by using this code as Java added to wordpress:

jwplayer().onDisplayClick(function() { jwplayer().play(); });
Is there any way to format the above code the same way, because it is easier for me to set it up as Java.

Comment: There is not. You cannot use the isMobile() code with shorecode.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding the player via shortcode, and I was able to start/stop on video clicking by using this code as Java added to wordpress:

```
jwplayer().onDisplayClick(function() { jwplayer().play(); });
```

Is there any way to format the above code the same way, because it is easier for me to set it up as Java.

Comment: There is not. You cannot use the isMobile() code with shorecode.